# How to resolve No value accessor for form control name in Angular?

Tags: angular, forms, input, storybook

I am trying to achieve the following where I can wrap `<app-test-field>` components inside the `<form>` tag where I can dynamically bind in `formControlName` and `formGroup` to TestField input as follows using Angular with StorybookJS.

However, I am encountering the following errors:

- core.mjs:11483 ERROR Error: NG01203: No value accessor for form control name: 'name'.
- core.mjs:11483 ERROR Error: NG01050: formControlName must be used with a parent formGroup directive.  You'll want to add a formGroup directive and pass it an existing FormGroup instance (you can create one in your class).

In **TestField.stories.js**

Here is the template for my Angular component in StorybookJS.

```
<form [formGroup]="sampleForm">
  <!-- name input -->
  <app-test-field [label]="label" [formControlName]="formControlName"></app-test-field>  
  <!-- email input... -->  
  <!-- more inputs... --> 
</form>
```

In **test-field.component.html**

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="{{ formControlName }}">{{ label }}</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    [formControlName]="formControlName"
    [id]="formControlName"
  /><br />
</div>
```

In **test-field.component.ts**

```
import { Component, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-field',
  templateUrl: './test-field.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-field.component.css'],
})
export class TestFieldComponent {
  @Input() label: string = '';
  @Input() formControlName: string = '';
}
```

I researched most examples online where the input itself is wrapped around with the `<form>` tag in the component itself as below:

```
<form [formGroup]="registerForm">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Name</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [ngClass]="inputDanger" formControlName="name"><br/>
    </span>
    <br/>
  </div>
</form>
```

But I want to remove `form` tag such that the end goal would be the following where input is a component by itself wrapped inside a `<form>` tag as follows:

```
<form [formGroup]="sampleForm">
  <!-- name input -->
  <app-test-field [label]="label" [formControlName]="formControlName"></app-test-field>  
  <!-- email input... -->  
  <!-- more inputs... --> 
</form>
```

Can someone help me with this? Is anything missing?

Comment: https://levelup.gitconnected.com/title-mastering-angular-control-value-accessor-a-guide-for-angular-developer-89057cbadbc8
I think it will be helpful for you.

Comment: Thanks for the link! Will give this a read. Its an article with membership payment required to access this content. Is it the same case for you?

Comment: Or make a Custom form Control or use ViewProvider like this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73455294/how-do-i-get-access-to-from-control-from-another-component-in-angular/73457780#73457780) -one e.g. among a lot-

Comment: I have added the solution can you please check and let me know if is there are any problem ?

Comment: @Chintan Dhokai Don't post paywall articles please

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/range/src/value-accessor/range-value-accessor.ts) an example of a value accessor

Comment: I have posted answer in this post in stackoverflow https://stackoverflow.com/a/77314219/12089970

Answer (score 0):

To use the control in a separate component without the wrapping form, you can use Angular's NgControl

Here is an example of usage in the case of the question:

In **test-field.component.ts**:

the ngControl is passed in the constructor and has some required functions

```
import { Component, Input, Optional, Self } from '@angular/core';
import { NgControl } from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-test-field',
  templateUrl: './test-field.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./test-field.component.scss'],
})
export class TestFieldComponent {
  @Input() label: string = '';

  onChange: any = () => {};
  onTouch: any = () => {};

  constructor(@Optional() @Self() public ngControl: NgControl) {
    if (this.ngControl != null) {
      this.ngControl.valueAccessor = this;
    }
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {}

  registerOnChange(fn: any): void {
    this.onChange = fn;
  }

  registerOnTouched(fn: any): void {
    this.onTouch = fn;
  }

  writeValue(value: any): void {}
}
```

Now, using the ngControl in **test-field.component.html**:

```
<div class="form-group">
  <label for="{{ ngControl?.name }}">{{ label }}</label>
  <input
    type="text"
    class="form-control"
    [formControl]="ngControl?.control"
    [id]="ngControl?.name"
  /><br />
</div>
```

In **TestField.stories.js** you can only remove the 'formControlName' input as it is no longer needed:

```
<form [formGroup]="sampleForm">
  <!-- name input -->
  <app-test-field [label]="label"></app-test-field>  
  <!-- email input... -->  
  <!-- more inputs... --> 
</form>
```

Comment: In my component html form, I am getting `Type 'AbstractControl<any, any> | null | undefined' is not assignable to type 'FormControl<any>'`.